# Edit raster values above 100 in Euclidean distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a dataset I have Euclidean Distance'ized. I need to use this dataset in Machine Learning as a way to tell the AI what values have larger influence on an event than others. When we move further away than 100 meters we assume that we no longer affect the probability of said event happening.

So, what I need to be able to do, is to edit all values above 100 m, so that all values above 100 m, get the value 100 m, as these don't affect the area lesser and lesser but the same as at 100 m?

I'm using ArcMap 10.8 but I don't think the version matters that much.

Comment: Raster calculator Con(ED <100, ED, 100). Output is float like original,  reclassification produces integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool on your Euclidean Distance output raster to set all values greater than 100 to be equal to 100. As long as you keep the default missing_values parameter set to DATA you can ignore all you values less than 100 - the original value will carry through unchanged.

This way you can also play around with if 100m is actually the appropriate threshold of "doesn't have any impact beyond that distance". If later in your research it looks like 50m or 200m would be a better threshold, you can just run a new version of Reclassify using a different threshold.

And you are correct, which version of ArcGIS you are using doesn't matter here. Reclassify is available in all recent versions of Desktop and Pro.

Comment: That was a lot more simple than first anticipated, I was trying to use Raster Calculator, and what I came up with there, was mad (and it didn't work). I don't know why I didn't think of this...

Comment: You could probably do something similar using the Con() function in raster calculator, but it's definitely more confusing for a case like this. Con() might be helpful if you found you needed to apply a more complex function to your variable (i.e. the variable is exponentially really influential up close, sort of influential in the mid distance, and not influential past a threshold.)